# localized characters halting the execution of a markdown/pandoc presentation

Tags: markdown, rstudio, pandoc

If I start a new `.Rmd` Presentation document in RStudio

````
---
title: "Unbetitled"
author: "Unbeknown"
date: "Tuesday, July 01, 2014"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide 1

Custom text

## Slide 2

Lorem ipsum

```{r}
hist(rnorm(100))
```
````

save it as encoding UTF-8 and hit 'Knit HTML', I get the desired output (preview window pops up with slides). But if I add (e.g. on a slide) localized characters, such as š, č, ć and ž, I get an error saying (I've censored direct paths with ...):

```
.../Pandoc/pandoc encoding_issues_pandoc.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output encoding_issues_pandoc.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --variable transition=0.4 --template ...\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\ioslides\default.html --mathjax --variable mathjax-url:https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML --variable ioslides-url=...\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\ioslides\ioslides-13.5.1 
output file: encoding_issues_pandoc.knit.md

.../Pandoc/pandoc encoding_issues_pandoc.utf8.md --to ioslides_presentation.lua --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output ...\Temp\RtmpMDfdFm\ioslides-output2298674c3f51.html --data-dir . 
pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xc4': Data.Text.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command '.../Pandoc/pandoc encoding_issues_pandoc.utf8.md --to ioslides_presentation.lua --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output ...\Temp\RtmpMDfdFm\ioslides-output2298674c3f51.html --data-dir .' had status 1 
Execution halted
```

If I remove the offending characters, document gets converted correctly. Can someone shed some light on what's going on here?

*update 1*

If I 'knit' the document by hand using the command RStudio uses

```
pandoc encoding_issues_pandoc.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output encoding_issues_pandoc.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --variable transition=0.4 --template ..\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\ioslides\default.html --mathjax --variable mathjax-url:https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML --variable ioslides-url=..\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\ioslides\ioslides-13.5.1
```

it goes through fine. Issue arises when I do the second part, when a `.lua` file is called.

```
pandoc encoding_issues_pandoc.md --to ..\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\ioslides\ioslides_presentation.lua --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output test --data-dir .
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smaller'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smaller'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'fig_caption'
WARNING: Undefined function 'base64_images'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smaller'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
WARNING: Undefined function 'smart'
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xc4': Data.Text.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

Comment: Windows or Linux (line endings)? And have you checked (w/file or similar) that it actually is being saved as utf8 when you include the symbols?

Comment: @OliverMatthews I'm on Windows. Notepad++ says it's saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @OliverMatthews I've updated the question with some findings, can you make anything out of it?

Comment: Give a try to the difference between "UTF-8" and "UTF-8 without BOM". I use notepad++ under windows, which can distinguish between the two.

Comment: @KağanKayal I think the problem is the way pandoc handles the file, not the way it's encoded.